# Test significance using Type II ANOVA following Type III ANOVA?

Tags: anova, interaction, glmm, sums-of-squares

I hope you can help me with a theoretical question about how to proceed in my analysis. I have come across many posts discussing differences between Type II and III SS Anovas, however, because I don't know which effects impact on my response variable, I am interested in finding out about interactions as well as 'single' fixed effects and this is where I got stuck.

I am from a behaviour/biology background rather than maths so I hope you can help me with my issue.

I am running a glmm in R with the lme4 package (Gamma distribution). Because I am interested to find out what impacts on my response variable, I included fixed effects based on biological and ecological background knowledge. However, because nothing is known about my research question, I don't have a specific hypothesis of interest, rather, I would like to know which, if any, of my fixed effects do have an impact.
I hope you can understand my question from this theoretical approach as my data are sensitive, I can't really go into too much detail. I am measuring how an animals stress response varies depending on various factors such as sex, age, season,... and my random effect is animal ID (5 levels) to control for repeated sampling.

Now my understanding is, that because there are interactions in my model, I should run a Type III Anova (car package) to find out whether the interactions have a significant impact.

So far so good. However, this Type III Anova tells me that none of my interactions are significant (which is fine, as I mentioned above, I put them in based on biological knowledge but there is nothing that says they have to be).

Following this, however, I am still interested whether the fixed effects by themselves would have a significant effect on my response variable. From my understanding, I would have to run a Type II Anova to find out about that, because in a Type III they would be 'masked' by the interactions containing them (and in fact, when I run a Type II one of the fixed effects on its 'own' now is significant).

I am wondering

1: is it reasonable to argue that, following investigating interactions with a Type III Anova, a Type II was used to investigate the 'stand-alone' fixed effects

2: If this is possible, would I run the Type II Anova on the exact same model, or on one including all the fixed effects but none of the interactions?

Because of problems associated with step-wise selection, I would like to avoid doing that and instead am running a model with fixed effects and interactions based on biological and ecological knowledge. My n=43, so there is only so many interactions I can include before the model becomes over parametized, but I am running a 'maximum possible' model based on my data.

My data is unbalanced (which as I understand would support my argument that I use a Type II Anova after investigating interactions).

I have been at this for a few days now but am somewhat stuck at this current point and really hope someone can shed some light on this for me :)

Comment: From my understanding there is no difference in the estimates of interaction effects between the choice of a Type II and Type III ANOVA. It is only the main effects that are different, since the hypotheses tested are different. See also Langsrud, O. (2003). ANOVA for unbalanced data: Use Type II instead of Type III sums of squares, *Statistics and Computing*, 13(2): 163-167